# How do I get the button function to work with my "Lapis, Papyrus, Scalpellus" game?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm incredibly new to coding and I'm having issues getting my JS code to work. I can't get my code to respond to the buttons I've created for the player input.

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
  <style>
  </style>
  <body>
    <h1>Lapis, Papyrus, Scalpellus!</h1>     
    <h2>Join the game of centuries and see if you can be a conqueror like Ancient Rome in this original version of Rock, Paper, Scissors.</h2>
  <h3>Make Your Choice</h3>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="lapis">Lapis</button>
      <button id="papyrus" >Papyrus</button>
      <button id="scalpellus" >Scalpellus</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
  </script>
</html>
```

Here's the JS:

```
const player = {
  currentChoice: null
};
const computer = {
  currentChoice: null
};
let choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];

player.currentChoice = choices[0];

function computerChooses() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex];
}

function compareChoices() {
  computerChooses();
  if (computer.currentChoice === player.currentChoice) {
    displayResults("Tie. Both Choose " + computer.currentChoice);
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
      displayResults(
        "Player Wins! " +
          player.currentChoice +
          " Beats " +
          computer.currentChoice +
          ".");
    } else {
      displayResults(
        "Computer Wins! " +
          computer.currentChoice +
          " Beats " +
          player.currentChoice +
          ".");
    }
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
      displayResults(
        "Player Wins! " +
          player.currentChoice +
          " Beats " +
          computer.currentChoice +
          ".");
    } else {
      displayResults(
        "Computer Wins! " +
          computer.currentChoice +
          " Beats " +
          player.currentChoice +
          ".");
    }
  } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
    if (player.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
      displayResults(
        "Player Wins! " +
          player.currentChoice +
          " Beats " +
          computer.currentChoice +
          ".");
    } else {
      displayResults(
        "Computer Wins! " +
          computer.currentChoices +
          " Beats " +
          player.currentChoices +
          ".");
    }
  }
}

function displayResults(result) {
  const resultText = document.createElement("p");
  resultText.innerText = result;

  document.body.appendChild(resultText);
}
compareChoices();
```

My issue, again, is that the computer will randomly choose the prompt, which is good, but I don't know how to get the buttons to work for the player to be able to make a choice. Right now the default is set to Lapis for the player choice. I think I need to create an eventListener for the buttons, but I just don't have the knowledge yet to be able to get this done on my own and for my code to run successfully.
Any advice and pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

one way is to

remove `compareChoices` from onload then add it onclick in your HTML buttons.

```js
const player = {
    currentChoice: null
  };
  const computer = {
    currentChoice: null
  };
  let choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];
  
  player.currentChoice = choices[0];

  var btnLapis = document.getElementById("")
  
  function computerChooses() {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex];
  }
  
  function compareChoices() {
    computerChooses();
    if (computer.currentChoice === player.currentChoice) {
      displayResults("Tie. Both Choose " + computer.currentChoice);
    } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
      if (player.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
        displayResults(
          "Player Wins! " +
            player.currentChoice +
            " Beats " +
            computer.currentChoice +
            ".");
      } else {
        displayResults(
          "Computer Wins! " +
            computer.currentChoice +
            " Beats " +
            player.currentChoice +
            ".");
      }
    } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
      if (player.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
        displayResults(
          "Player Wins! " +
            player.currentChoice +
            " Beats " +
            computer.currentChoice +
            ".");
      } else {
        displayResults(
          "Computer Wins! " +
            computer.currentChoice +
            " Beats " +
            player.currentChoice +
            ".");
      }
    } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
      if (player.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
        displayResults(
          "Player Wins! " +
            player.currentChoice +
            " Beats " +
            computer.currentChoice +
            ".");
      } else {
        displayResults(
          "Computer Wins! " +
            computer.currentChoices +
            " Beats " +
            player.currentChoices +
            ".");
      }
    }
  }
  
  function displayResults(result) {
    const resultText = document.createElement("p");
    resultText.innerText = result;
  
    document.body.appendChild(resultText);
  }
//   compareChoices();
```

```html
  <body>
    <h1>Lapis, Papyrus, Scalpellus!</h1>     
    <h2>Join the game of centuries and see if you can be a conqueror like Ancient Rome in this original version of Rock, Paper, Scissors.</h2>
  <h3>Make Your Choice</h3>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="lapis" onclick="compareChoices()">Lapis</button>
      <button id="papyrus"  onclick="compareChoices()">Papyrus</button>
      <button id="scalpellus"  onclick="compareChoices()">Scalpellus</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Man, I'm the greenest grass you've ever seen when it comes to coding. Thanks a lot, this helped out!

Comment: Glad that helped. Don't forget to check it as accepted answer.

Comment: Oh wait hey, how do I get the players response to change from just being Lapis, no matter what button I click, it stays the same?

Comment: @FuzzyVolpitta this issue is in your function. try to figure it out. and I will try to fix it for you if I have time later.

Comment: Info that may help you. the player click should not be randomized, the value should be according to the button the user click.

Comment: @FuzzyVolpitta, hey there. yesterday I built a simple rock scissors paper game. check it and see if it's useful. [rock scissors paper game](https://codepen.io/Mad7Dragon/pen/BaxPVPa)

Comment: thanks I've been studying these past few days to come up with an answer. Honestly, I don't have the knowledge base built up yet for JS to be able to communicate clearly. This is my first week dipping my toes into JS and man is it dense on first impression. I really appreciate the advice and help.

Comment: @FuzzyVolpitta no worries, I felt exactly the same when I started and I'm still learning and practicing everyday. Learn it step by step and do as many projects as you can. I actually like the [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/). It's old and not that updated, but still can learn almost all basics from it. I really love its design and structure. Once you learned js functions, you'll see how amazing and powerful it is. So Keep up the good work and good luck.